# PyTorch dataloader shows odd behavior with string dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

I'm working on an NLP problem and am using PyTorch. **For some reason, my dataloader is returning malformed batches.** I have input data that comprises sentences and integer labels.
The sentences can either a list of sentences or a list of list of tokens. I will later convert the tokens to integers in a downstream component.

```py
list_labels = [ 0, 1, 0]

# List of sentences.
list_sentences = [ 'the movie is terrible',
                   'The Film was great.',
                   'It was just awful.']

# Or list of list of tokens.
list_sentences = [['the', 'movie', 'is', 'terrible'],
                  ['The', 'Film', 'was', 'great.'],
                  ['It', 'was', 'just', 'awful.']]
```

I created the following custom dataset:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, sentences, labels):

        self.sentences = sentences
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        result = {}
        result['sentences'] = self.sentences[i]
        result['label'] = self.labels[i]
        return result

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
```

When I provide input in the form of a list of sentences, the dataloader **correctly** returns batches of complete sentences. Note that `batch_size=2`:

```py
list_sentences = [ 'the movie is terrible', 'The Film was great.', 'It was just awful.']
list_labels = [ 0, 1, 0]


dataset = MyDataset(list_sentences, list_labels)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2)

batch = next(iter(dataloader))
print(batch)
# {'sentences': ['the movie is terrible', 'The Film was great.'], <-- Great! 2 sentences in batch!
#  'label': tensor([0, 1])}
```

The batch correctly contains two sentences and two labels because `batch_size=2`.

**However**, when I instead enter the sentences as pre-tokenized list of list of token, I get weird results:

```py
list_sentences = [['the', 'movie', 'is', 'terrible'], ['The', 'Film', 'was', 'great.'], ['It', 'was', 'just', 'awful.']]
list_labels = [ 0, 1, 0]


dataset = MyDataset(list_sentences, list_labels)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2)

batch = next(iter(dataloader))
print(batch)
# {'sentences': [('the', 'The'), ('movie', 'Film'), ('is', 'was'), ('terrible', 'great.')], <-- WHAT?
#  'label': tensor([0, 1])}
```

Note that this batch's `sentences` is one single list with *tuples of word pairs*. **I was expecting `sentences` to be a list of two lists**, like this:

```py
{'sentences': [['the', 'movie', 'is', 'terrible'], ['The', 'Film', 'was', 'great.']
```

What is going on?

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. this seems like a real problem - pytorch should be able to collate batches of strings. I can see many cases where you might want to process strings after the dataloader step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is because the default `collate_fn` does the [following](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cdc2d2843b2bb7ef1f7192718a24bfabb93b3d36/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py#L76-L83) when it has to collate `list`s (which is the case for `['sentences']`):

```py
# [...]
elif isinstance(elem, container_abcs.Sequence):
    # check to make sure that the elements in batch have consistent size
    it = iter(batch)
    elem_size = len(next(it))
    if not all(len(elem) == elem_size for elem in it):
        raise RuntimeError('each element in list of batch should be of equal size')
    transposed = zip(*batch)
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
```

The "problem" happens because, in the last two lines, it'll recursively call `zip(*batch)` while the batch is a `container_abcs.Sequence` (and `list` is), and `zip` behaves like this.

As you can see:

```py
batch = [['the', 'movie', 'is', 'terrible'], ['The', 'Film', 'was', 'great.']]
list(zip(*batch))

# [('the', 'The'), ('movie', 'Film'), ('is', 'was'), ('terrible', 'great.')]
```

I don't see a workaround in your case, except implementing a new collator and passing it to the `DataLoader(..., collate_fn=mycollator)`. For instance, a simple *ugly* one could be:

```py
def mycollator(batch):
    assert all('sentences' in x for x in batch)
    assert all('label' in x for x in batch)
    return {
        'sentences': [x['sentences'] for x in batch],
        'label': torch.tensor([x['label'] for x in batch])
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have dug down further into the batch generator like you did.

Comment: I should have also recognized that when you see pairs of things at the same index of two lists like (`'the', 'The')`, it's probably the output of a `zip()`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to encode the strings as bytes and in your `Dataset` and then decode them in your forward pass. This is useful if you want to include strings for metadata (like the file path the data came from), but don't actually need to pass the data into your model.

For example:

```
class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __next__(self):
        return np.array("this is a sentence").bytes()
```

And then in your forward pass you would do:

```
sentences: List[str] = []
for sentence in batch:
    sentences.append(sentence.decode("ascii"))
```